# Winsock network c++

Tags: winsock

I want to learn winsock network programming in C or C++  . but I don't know
which tutorial to learn .

I've found this tutorial http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html but the author is using UNIX .I don't know if the code in this tutorial will compile without errors on windows.

I've downloaded Network Programming for Microsoft Windows , Second Edition (Microsoft Programming Series) book but it has no c++ section ...... any help ??

Comment: copy the code, compile and see for yourself....

Comment: plus it has a comment in the site for windows programmers..... read it.

Answer (score 0):

The "Network Programming for Microsoft Windows" is a good resource to start socket programming under Windows.

The winsock library is a plain C library including the Microsoft extensions to the Berkeley socket function set. You cab use winsockets and link the C import library to you C++ application. The header files are prepared for C++ so that you don't have to enclose them in `#ifdef __cplusplus` guards.